# How to stay on particular page after perform delete in jquery serverside datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working with jquery server-side datatable. I want to stay on a particular page from where  I deleted the record. 
For example: Suppose I have 30 records and page size of datatable is 10. I selected second page and delete the 15 no record, at this time i want to stay on this second no. page.

But in my case every time when i performed delete it put me in first page. How to set the number of page after delete record from a particular page number?

My code is as bellow:-

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table-responsive" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Class
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="IsDeleteCall" id="IsDeleteCall" value="false" />
    <input type="hidden" name="IdToDelete" id="IdToDelete" value=" " />
    <input type="hidden" name="displayStartIndex" id="hdndisplayStartIndex" value=" " />
</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bSortClasses": false,
            "bSortable": true,
            "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
            "bAutoWidth": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            //"sScrollX": "100%",
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Home/GetCustomers/",
            "iDisplayStart": 10,
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
                var colCount = aoData[1].value;
                var sSearch = fnGetKey(aoData, "sSearch");
                var sSort = fnGetKey(aoData, "iSortCol_0");
                var sDir = fnGetKey(aoData, "sSortDir_0");

                var jsonData = {
                    sSortDir: sDir,
                    sSort: sSort,
                    sSearch: sSearch,
                    sEcho: aoData[0].value,
                    iDisplayLength: aoData[4].value,
                    iDisplayStart: $('#hdndisplayStartIndex').val() == 0 ? aoData[3].value : $('#hdndisplayStartIndex').val(),
                    // iDisplayStart: aoData[3].value,
                    IsDeleteCall: $('#IsDeleteCall').val(),
                    IdToDelete: $('#IdToDelete').val()
                }

                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": jsonData,
                    "success": fnCallback
                });
            },
            "fnInitComplete": function () {
            }

        });




    });

    function fnGetKey(aoData, sKey) {
        for (var i = 0, iLen = aoData.length; i < iLen; i++) {
            if (aoData[i].name == sKey) {
                return aoData[i].value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    function deleteRow(e) {

        var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
        $('#IsDeleteCall').val(true);
        $('#IdToDelete').val(id);
        $(e.target).parent().parent().attr('userId', id);
        var displayStart = $(e.target).attr('displayStart');
        $('#hdndisplayStartIndex').val(displayStart);
        table.row($('tr[userid=' + id + ']')).remove().draw(true);
        $('#hdndisplayStartIndex').val(0);
        // table.row($(e.target).parent().parent()).remove().draw(false);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Can you send an AJAX request to delete the records you want?

Comment: yeah sure let me paste my code.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still finding this question, DataTables 1.10.8 (and above) provides great options to the .Draw() method which allow you to control what happens to the paging and sorting after table redraw.

To stay on the same page and update the sorting/filtering, the code you're looking for is:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable.draw('full-hold');
//or
$('#myTable').DataTable.draw(false);
```

**Quick reference to draw() arguments:**

**'full-reset' or true (default)** - the ordering and search will be recalculated and the rows redrawn in their new positions. The paging will be reset back to the first page.

**'full-hold' or false** - the ordering and search will be recalculated and the rows redrawn in their new positions. The paging will not be reset - i.e. the current page will still be shown.

**'page'** - ordering and search will not be updated and the paging position held where is was. This is useful for paging (i.e. page()) when data has not been changed between draws.

Reference to DataTables documentation:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution [here](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/573/how-to-stay-on-current-page-after-re-draw)

I used this in my code. There is no need to do anything special only add this code before and after fndraw function and this is working code.

```
/* when updating the table */
bResetDisplay = false; /* override default behaviour */
oTable.fnDraw();
bResetDisplay = true; /* restore default behaviour */
```

And also Add these are  parameters for the table: specially   **bStateSave**

```
"bProcessing": true, // shows 'processing' label
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource": "/cds/",
"bStateSave": true, // presumably saves state for reloads
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me.

```
"sDom": "<'col-xs-12<'row'<'col-sm-4 col-xs-12'<'pull-left'f>><'col-sm-8 button col-xs-12'>>tr<'col-xs-12'<'row'<'col-sm-4 col-xs-12'l><'col-sm-4 col-xs-12'i><'col-sm-4 col-xs-12'p><'clearfix'>>>>>",
            "sAjaxSource": $("#user_table").attr('action'),  
            "bStateSave": true, // presumably saves state for reloads
```